# 2001 Ford Focus ZX3 dohc automatic keeps stalling when I turn it on in the morning

Tags: ford, focus

I had to replace a broken alternator bracket tensioner pulley and idler pulley along with the drive belt. Everything was working fine except the car was idling rough and kept stalling when I turned it on in the morning. I have to keep my foot on the gas while it warmed up enough to stay on. I changed the vacuum hose and PCV valve but that didn't solve the problem, it got worse! Now the transmission randomly kicks which didn't happen before. I'm not sure if that's related or not but I know it didn't happen before. There's also a strong gasoline smell and like oil burning. I do have a power steering leak somewhere but I already know what that smells like and this is totally different. I checked the fuel lines but didn't see any leaks. I went back to re-check my work and everything looks right. Any advice?

Comment: My first thought is that you left a connector off or swapped a couple of connectors that are the same.  It's not common that nearby connectors are interchangeable but I've seen a few.  Go back and double-check your wiring.